# split the 4.00pm as 4.00 pm and :2:30pm as 2:30 pm in python

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I am trying to work out a simple function to split the numeric and alpha,

e.g:
"Date : 16.06.2016 Start Time (with time zone) **:2:30pm** to **4:00Pm** End Time (with time zone)"

after code:
"Date : 16.06.2016 Start Time (with time zone) : **2:30 pm** to **4:00 Pm** End Time (with time zone)"

```
    enter code here

x="Date : 16.06.2016 Start Time (with time zone) :2:30pm to 4:00Pm End Time (with time zone)"
p = re.compile("([0-9])([([a-z])")

for m in p.findall(x):

      print (m)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import re
y=re.sub("(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])", " ", x)
z=re.sub("(?<=\s):(?=[0-9])", " : ", y)
```

Comment: x="i will come at :4:30pm"  for this input i'm getting "i will come at :4:30 pm" but i need "i will come at : 4:30 pm"